# How to start Viber in minimized mode when booting Windows 7?

Tags: boot, viber

I want Viber get started automatically but get minimized in system tray also - I don't want to see it on my task pane.

How can I do that?

p.s. Going in the Viber application setting and found nothing there.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If they don't add the option to do so, it's not possible, sadly enough. You could always suggest the viber developers to add the option @ http://support.viber.com/customer/portal/emails/new

Answer (score 4):

As of **2015-05** it seems it's not possible to make **Viber** autostart minimized to **System tray**.

However, it's at least possible to prevent **Viber** main window popping out on startup, instead keeping Viber **minimized to Windows Taskbar**, not **System tray**.

Here's how to prevent **Viber** popping out on **Window 7 startup**:

1. Navigate to **C:\Users\YOUR USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs**

[image: Viber shortcut]

2. Find **Viber** shortcut
3. Right mouse click on **Viber** shortcut - **Properties** - select **Shortcut** Tab - **Run:** from dropdown menu select **Minimized** - **OK**

[image: Minimized]

This will make **Viber** start **minimized to Windows Taskbar** from where you can close **Viber** window and leave **Viber** icon only in **System tray**:

[image: Taskbar]

Obviously, we should all suggest **Viber** developers to add an option to **Autostart Viber minimized to System tray** @ [https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/emails/new](http://support.viber.com/customer/portal/emails/new)

Answer (score 3):

Viber is launched with the command "viber.exe StartMinimized". This "StartMinimized" argument seems to mean that they intended Viber to start minimized. But it only works when Viber is pinned to the taskbar.

That being said, your best bet is to contact them at http://support.viber.com/customer/portal/emails/new to report that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small AHK script to solve this problem.

Copy it in same directory as `Viber.exe` (`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Viber`). and then associate it with AHK and update the startup entry to `ViberTray.ahk`

Source:

```
#NoTrayIcon

ProcessId(exe_name)
{
  Process, Exist, %exe_name%
  return %ErrorLevel%
}

PID := ProcessId("Viber.exe")
Run viber.exe

if (0 == PID) {
  WinWait ahk_exe viber.exe
  WinWaitActive ahk_exe viber.exe,,2
  WinClose ahk_exe viber.exe
}
```

Comment: Your script doesn't work.

Comment: @Suncatcher Updated!

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified VarunAgw's solution to this:

```
Run Viber.exe
WinWait ahk_exe Viber.exe,, 10

if (0 == %ErrorLevel%) {
  WinClose ahk_exe Viber.exe
}
```

Now it works for me just fine.

Answer (score 0):

VB NET

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim myProcesses() As Process = Process.GetProcesses
        For Each p As Process In myProcesses
            If p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("Viber") Then
                p.CloseMainWindow()
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: It works plain and simply... :) You can start it with windows with windows with some seconds delay...

Answer (score 0):

```
'Vb script ,you must add APIWrapperCOM.dll to System
Dim WshShell

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set obj = CreateObject("APIWrapperCOM.APIWrapper")
WshShell.Run "C:\Users\ura\AppData\Local\Viber\Viber.exe", 5
WScript.Sleep(1500)
winHandle = obj.FindWindow("Viber")
obj.KillWindow(winHandle)
'*** End
```

It works reliably.