# How to start Spotify in minimized mode when booting Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, spotify

I am trying to start Spotify in minimized mode when booting Windows 10.  I tried to use this AHK solution posted on another question, [How to start Viber in minimized mode when booting Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/a/1093763/364367), but it does not work for Spotify.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Spotify has a setting for that. Any reason you’re not using that?

Comment: Unfortunately, the collapse settings in the tray when running in Spotify is not.

Answer (score 2):

Specify `--minimized` in the launch options: Run `path\to\spotify.exe --minimized`.
The window is still created, but it will at least be minimized, and thus won't steal window focus.

---

Found this out by noticing it was a choice in advanced settings to start minimized on system boot, so I investigated the startup entry Spotify created with Autoruns from Windows Sysinternals (there are many ways to set a program to start automatically, this tool lists all if not most). The startup entry additionally passes the flag `--autostart` to Spotify.exe, but it doesn't seem to have any effect so I left it out.

Answer (score 2):

This takes a few steps but its not too bad. Got tired of waiting for spotify to add simple feature that many other apps have like plex, steam, discord etc...

Download and install auto hot key - https://www.autohotkey.com/

Right click on your desktop> New> Autohotkey script

Right click on your new autohotkey script and click "Edit Script"

Paste in the following code:

```
if WinExist("Spotify Premium")
WinClose ;
```

Make sure you added a line break between the first and second statements.

Save the file

Right click on the script you made and compile script

Copy the new compiled script

Press Windows key + R

Put in the box > "shell:startup" and hit ok

paste the script in this folder

DONE

Reboot and it will work now, make sure you have close to system tray enabled in the Spotify settings

If you don't have spotify premium you have to change the script to whatever spotify is called for free version I'm not sure maybe someone in the comments can help.

The full solution is provided here: https://www.reddit.com/r/spotify/comments/oukrdk/howto_spotify_start_minimized_and_in_system_tray/.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1151430)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added the original answer.

Comment: Because it's a better answer now, I have upvoted it.